# How can the passphrase matter besides the very most obvious patterns?

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, passphrase

Let's say that my passphrase is:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapassword9
```

Yes, it looks ridiculous. But only because we already know it. An attacker, trying to brute-force their way into this passphrase, has zero knowledge about it. That is, unless they have somehow heard or seen me boast about how I always pick passwords where I mostly press the same key over and over followed by an English word and then one digit.

They simply have no idea that I use a password like this.

I would expect any brute-force program to check every dictionary word, and perhaps various verified (through leaked databases and whatnot) common passwords such as "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or "qwerty". But then we have the infinite number of variations. Somebody might be using a password such as:

```
password1e
```

I can buy that "password1" is an easily brute-forced password, because it's such a simple and easily tested variation, likely to be used by some. But in this case, we follow with "e". That already seems very unlikely that they would brute-force-test with. It immediately strays too far from what can be reasonably expected. And again, they are "blind" to this, so they would also have to test for "passworde1" and "e1password" and "1epassword", etc.

It seems to me that no brute-force mechanism could crack any non-ultra-trivial password. In terms of sheer numbers, "password1e" is identical in difficulty to "a0dLsXDdLs", a passphrase with the same number of characters but *looking* (to a human) much more random and thus strong. But the brute-forcer doesn't care if it's "password1e" or "a0dLsXDdLs", or rather, it *cannot* care since it would have to check everything in some kind of order, and they have no reason that it's going to be a dictionary word for those specific beginning characters and then followed by the more random "1e". So it won't test that "first" unless it's been specifically programmed to do so. And if it has, then it has prior knowledge about what the password is. Which we don't in reality.

I have to say that I'm starting to feel skeptical that passphrases (which aren't *extremely* obvious) can actually be cracked by normal computers. Either that, or I'm grossly misunderstanding security again. (As I have repeatedly done in life.)

Comment: You are assuming that the attacker doesn't know your pattern and tries to crack your password using only one method. We have a few questions here assessing the security of password patterns.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I think the top answers there don't look very good. Schroeder's answer here is probably better because it mentions the threat of leaked passwords.

Comment: @reed: I agree that the highest voted answers there don't address everything. But there are many answers which also cover more aspects. And the basic idea of the question is the same: using some secret but trivial algorithm (and thus not that much secret) to generate easy to remember passwords. As stated in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24467/37315): *"Rule of thumb 1: if it is easy to remember, then it is easy to guess for the attacker."*.

Comment: Note that `password1e` has been seen 29 times on haveibeenpwned (https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords). Then `passworde1` 223 times, `e1password` 15 times, `1epassword` 58 times. That means they are actually worthy variations to include in a hacker's list, so your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, it's definitely a duplicate, so technically it should be closed, I agree. But I just wanted to say that in this case, thanks to this duplicate, we got the chance to see another good (actually even better) answer, which would not have been posted if this question had been closed at once.

Comment: `password1e` tested on haveibeenpwned.com; result: *This password has been seen 29 times before*.  `a0dLsXDdLs` was not found.  QED.

Answer (score 2):

You defeat password brute-forcing not by the resulting pattern that is created but by the randomness of how the password was created.

`password1` is easily guessed because 1) it's used often, so it's in "Top 100" password dictionaries, and 2) it follows a normal pattern that people often choose (dictionary word followed by a digit). There is little randomness in how it is chosen.

If `password1e` is in a dictionary, and you use it, then the game is over. The fact that you have added one small addition to a normal and expected pattern adds time to guessing, yes, but if the brute-forcer tries this pattern, then game over. You've taken a known password and added a character. This has very low randomness, and it's an easily guessable pattern.

If your password `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapassword9` gets leaked, I now know your password pattern and I can design a brute-force approach for your accounts. Game over. It's long, sure, and if I'm trying to guess it character by character, it will take a long time. But once I know your pattern, the length is meaningless.

Password patterns are like hiding your house key under the mat. They work until someone knows where to look, then every password that uses the pattern is useless against this attacker.

In security, there is a concept known as [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), which says that a secure system should be able to remain secure even if an attacker knows how the system works.

- If I know your password pattern, then your password is not secure
- If you use a random password generator, then the password is secure even if every attacker in the world knows that you do that
- If you use 4 randomly chosen dictionary words, your password is secure *for quite a while* due to the size of a typical dictionary
- If you use 4 words that you choose yourself, your password is not so secure due to the small number of words the average person will think of (and yes, there is research directly into this, and the list of words is shockingly small)

The more randomness there is in the selection of a password, the more secure it is. Length does help, but length can be defeated by a known pattern.